# How to make an arbitrary number of variables (Java)

Tags: java, variables

In my program, I want to make the number of variables equal to the number of letters in a word. This is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CountString {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String w;
    Scanner raj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Word? ");
    w=raj.next();
    for(int i=0; i<w.length(); i++){
        int k_i=1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<w.length(); i++){
        System.out.print(k_i);
    }

}

}
```

The error I get is that k_i cannot be resolved to a variable. How would I make variables that specified way? And say I wanted to print the max of all the k_i's... how would I do that?

Comment: What you're doing there is not possible.  For something like that, you need to use an array or ArrayList.  What is your code trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ArrayList<Integer>` to hold the values. Use for loop to loop through it to print the values scanned.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Map` to store `key-value` pairs.

```
Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The core of your problem is that you are attempting define variables dynamically.  While some languages support this kind of thing, Java does not.  It never has, and it never will.

So you need to find an alternative way of doing what you are trying to do.  For example, the following is a literal translation of your example into real Java:

```
w = raj.next();
int k[] = new int[w.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < k.length; i++){
    k[i] = 1;
}
for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
    System.out.print(k[i]);
}
```

---

> And say I wanted to print the max of all the k_i's... how would I do that?

By iterating over the k[i]'s looking for the largest one.

---

I get the impression that you are new to Programming in general, and Java Programming in particular.  I'd advise you to go to your local bookstore and buy an introductory textbook on Programming in Java.  You could also go to the Oracle website and do the Java Tutorials ... but they are aimed more at people who already know how to program.

Answer (score 0):

I'd push each integer to an `ArrayList` instead.  You can then iterate through the list with a for loop and use the `Collections.max` method to find the maximum of the stored values.

Answer (score 0):

> The error I get is that k_i cannot be resolved to a variable. How
>   would I make variables that specified way?

Lifetime of k_i ends with the loop, declare it outside of loop so that definition remains valid under main scope.

> And say I wanted to print the max of all the k_i's... how would I do
>   that?

```
int k_i=0;
for(int i=0; i<w.length(); i++)
{ 
       k_i= k_i<i?i:k_i;     
}
```

And I dont understand rest of your requirement!!!

Answer (score 0):

You want letters, which are `chars` in java.

Try this:

```
char[] letters = new char[w.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++){
    letters[i] = w.charAt(i);
}
```